# ViewPager and AsyncTask for loading the Items

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've a `ViewPager` with an `PageAdapter` loading `ImageViews`.
The images displayed come from the internet and I use an AsyncTask for loading the `Bitmap` and then (if the Page hasn't been destroyed) assign it to the ImageView.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(container.getContext());
    new LoadImageTask(img,Data.getImageUrL(position)).execute();
    container.addView(img );
    return img;
}
```

So the `ImageView` has two states: loading or loaded. I need to track if the user waits for the image. So I implement this at the `LoadImageTask` **onPostExecute**:

```
if (loadListener != null) {
    loadListener.onImageLoaded(position);
}
```

And in the listener:

```
public void onImageLoaded(int position) {
    if (position == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        // Save record ..
    }
}
```

Since I only need to count the images displayed at the "Current Item of the ViewPager" this method is not enought because if the user moves to the item 5 for example, the `ViewPager` loads in cache the item 6. If the user waits enought time for this load (beeing the item 5 the current) the callback to onImageLoaded is lost (because the item 6 is not the currentItem at the moment, and then when the user moves to the item 6 I've no way of knowing if the image is loaded or not.

I was thinking in adding something like **[[PSEUDOCODE]]**:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

             if (mViewPager.isLoaded(posistion)){
                      // Save record ...
             }
        }
```

But I dont know how to retrieve if the corresponding view loaded the image or not at this moment. How can I do it?